# Inner border for list element

Tags: list, border

Is there such a thing as a border for the interior of list elements similar to what you can do in excel?  Similar to the property "inside" in excel:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well.. you can try this:

```css
ul > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
ul > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
```